# GSAP / Animate CC - how to pass the target mc currently being animated through to the onComplete function

Tags: javascript, gsap

In a javascript environment using create.js and GSAP in Adobe Animate CC, I am just trying to pass the target mc currently being animated through to the onComplete function.

I have tried `onComplete:myFunction(this)`, and  `onComplete:myFunction("shoe2")`, and the `onCompleteParams: ["shoe2"]` way, but nothing's working. Surely there's a simple way to pass the name of the target mc? I think it might need to use bind, but I've not been able to get that working either. Also tried `onComplete:myFunction.bind(this.shoe2)})`

```
var tl = gsap.timeline({repeat: 0, repeatDelay: 0});
tl.to(this.shoe, {duration:.0, x:10, y:-10, scaleX:1.2, scaleY:1.2})
.to(this.shoe2, {duration:.5, alpha:1, onComplete:myFunction, onCompleteParams: ["shoe2"]})

function myFunction(x){
    gsap.to(this.x, {duration:.05, x:-10, y:-10})
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm thinking this should be really simple.